# Android MediaController seekbar not refreshing

Tags: android, refresh, progress, seekbar, mediacontroller

I'm using a `MediaController` and `MediaPlayer` together, to create a simple audio player in Android, taken from an example I found here on this site.

However, after much search I could not find the solution to my problem: the progress/seek bar doesn't refresh while the music is playing. It just updates itself when something on the `MediaController` is pressed (Play/Pause, forward, etc).

Any easy fix for this that I'm not getting ?

NOTE: My `MediaController` is declared in `XML`, and my `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl` methods just make use of the `MediaPlayer` class.

Comment: Is the seekbar supposed to refresh automatically (through the MediaController/MediaPlayer APIs) or are you supposed to update it using code?

Comment: Well I wanted it to refresh automatically, since :
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer) is done. Unfortunately it only updates (without my code) when any of the MediaController's buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

`Mediaplayer` provides a method `getCurrentPosition()` you can put this in a thread to continously update the progressbar.

```
    public int getCurrentPositionInt(){
        if (player != null)
            return player.getCurrentPosition();
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Create a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) to continuously update the seekbar :

```
seekBar.setMax((getCurrentPositionInt() / 1000));
```

OR

```
MediaController.MediaPlayerControl mp;
mp.seekTo((getCurrentPositionInt() / 1000))
```

Comment: Thanks. Sad to know it won't update itself from the MediaPlayer attached. One more thing: how do I get the SeekBar from my MediaController ?

Comment: I have not worked on `MediaController` but documentation says that it takes care of synchronizing the controls with the state of the MediaPlayer. 
I think you can use MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.seekTo((getCurrentPositionInt() / 1000)) method to do that. rather  getting seekBar.

Comment: Yes it does synchronizes nicely, but which is strange is that it only refreshes when something is pressed. And seekTo won't work, already tried it :(

Comment: @Sayyam the seekTo method doesn't work sadly - the video just gets stuck. How would I get hold of the seekBar to try your other method?

Answer (score 0):

Im Sorry for my English!

you are showing the controller before the music player is ready.
You need to notify your activity from the controller when it is ready.

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                    Intent onPreparedIntent = new Intent("MP_READY");
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity).sendBroadcast(onPreparedIntent);
                }
```

Then you need to create a BroadcastReceiver in your activity and override his onReceive method to show the controller.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mpReadyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {            
        controller.show(0);
    }
};
```

You also need to register the receiver in your activity`s onResume().

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mpReadyReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("MP_READY"));
}
```

Now try to call controller.show only when it is necesary.

Be careful not creating more than one controller instance